# Unable to test controller action in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rspec

I am trying to test a controller action on a non-restful route.

`config/routes.rb`:

```
  match '/integration/:provider/callback' => "providers#manual_auth", as: :integration_callback
```

You can see that also via `rake routes`:

```
integration_callback /integration/:provider/callback(.:format) providers#manual_auth
```

In my spec file:

`spec/controllers/providers_controller_spec.rb`:

```
describe ProvidersController do
  describe '#manual_auth' do
    it 'hits the manual_auth action' do
      get :manual_auth, use_route: :integration_callback
    end
  end
end
```

That gives me an error of:

```
Failures:

  1) ProvidersController#manual_auth hits the manual_auth action
     Failure/Error: get :manual_auth, use_route: :integration_callback
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"providers", :action=>"manual_auth"}
```

However in `app/controllers/providers_controller.rb` I have

```
class ProvidersController < ApplicationController
  def manual_auth
    logger.info "Got into manual auth"
  end
end
```

I should mention I'm purposely avoiding a request spec here because I need to be able to access and set a session object(that lives in this `#manual_auth` action) which apparently can only be done in controller tests, not request specs.

Comment: Run `rake routes` and show the relative contents in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `integration_callback` has one parameter, which is `:provider`.

Try this:

```
get :manual_auth, provider: 'test', use_route: :integration_callback
```